# How to I check if element has a date greater than today (future date)

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I check if an element has a future date (date greater than today)?
I am using xslt and the format will always be MM/DD/YYYY
E.g `<EndDate>04/30/2016</EndDate>`

Comment: What language, if any are you using to parse the XML? Is the format always american MM/DD/YYYY ?

Comment: xslt and yes that will always the format

Comment: @Winston Which XSLT processor?

Comment: You need to say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - there's much more capability in 2.0 for manipulating dates. Also, it's a lot easier if you use ISO date formats rather than American format.

Comment: I am using XSLT version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 itself cannot give you the current date, but depending on which XSLT processor you are using you might be able to pull it from there. For example the Transform program we use is Java, so we do the following to get the current date:

`<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('MMMM d, yyyy'), java:java.util.Date.new())"/>`

You will need to do whatever your processor allows.